# Inputting a text to an executable file the moment it's executed

Tags: command-line, bash, python, password

i am bad at choosing titles but my problem is that I have an executable file that returns a value when i type the word `password` in it using the terminal, but the problem is the file require you to type the word `password` exactly after executing it, and semi-colons or pipes or && wont work for me, one of my friends said i could use python or perl in the terminal to solve this problem but he wasn't sure how it works nor am I.

So what I do basicly is executing the file using the command `./stdin` (the file's name is stdin) after that i write the word `password` but it says that i took a long time at writing the word `password` so as i said above i have tried semicolons and pipes and && `./stdin && password` `./stdin ; password` but they didn't gave anything to me, actually i had to stop them with ctrl+c , i was thinking of using the command `echo "password" | ./stdin` as someone on the internet has told me, but i didn't have the chance to try it right now because the file is in the school and the copy i have is broken, he said that the pipe symbol will input the output of the first command (right side) into the second command (left side).

Comment: the executable file have a very short time delay between the moment it's executed and the moment  i have to write the word password in it, my fastest one so far was 0.1 seconds delay using UP-Arrow key and it failed

Comment: Well `echo "password" | ./stdin` will work in most cases, but really it depends on the program. Also a more elegant way to do the same would be `<<<password ./stdin`.

Comment: @kos can you please explain the code `<<<pasword ./stdin` since it's a homework and i am realy eager to understand what does `<<<` means

Comment: Sure, it's a form of input redirection, and it's called Here String. When used, the input for the program is read from the string following `<<<` instead of from the terminal; that effectively in this context "fakes" an input typed into the terminal. If you're using that with spaces use single quotes to enclose the string: `<<<'password with spaces'`, and if you're using it with variables containing spaces use double-quotes in order to allow their expansion and at the same time in order to avoid to break the command due to the spaces: `<<<"$variable_containing_the_password_with_spaces"`.

Comment: @kos Thank you so much for your help you are the best :)

Comment: @kos post an answer.